# is it possible to model associative arrays in z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I am wondering if z3 supports associative arrays (aka maps)? If not is there a simple way to model such data structures using the current version of z3?

Answer (score 0):

Z3 has support for Arrays as defined by [SMT-Lib](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/ArraysEx.smt2) and it also has support for datatypes, either of them should allow you to model maps. A detailed example of using datatypes is found in the answer to this question: [a datatype contains a set in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343479/a-datatype-contains-a-set-in-z3). The [Z3 Guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide) also contains sections on how to use arrays as well as datatypes.